# Macro to Run and Loop through all worksheets but the first one

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below macro. I am looking for 2 things:

1) A better way to write it (I can't seem to make it work with ranges or any other way)

2) Have it loop through all worksheets (unknown amount, unknown names) except the first one.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-1]C"
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-2]C"
    Range("C5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-3]C"
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-4]C"
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-5]C"
    Range("C8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-6]C"
    Range("C9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-7]C"
    Range("C10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-8]C"
    Range("C11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-9]C"
    Range("C12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-10]C"
    Range("C13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-11]C"
    Range("C14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-12]C"
    Range("C15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-13]C"
    Range("C16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-14]C"
    Range("C17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-15]C"
    Range("C18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-16]C"
    Range("C19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-17]C"
    Range("C20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-18]C"
    Range("C21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-19]C"
    Range("C22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-20]C"
    Range("C23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-21]C"
    Range("C24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-22]C"
    Range("C25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-23]C"
    Range("C26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*R[-24]C"
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-1]C"
    Range("D4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-2]C"
    Range("D5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-3]C"
    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-4]C"
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-5]C"
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-6]C"
    Range("D9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-7]C"
    Range("D10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-8]C"
    Range("D11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-9]C"
    Range("D12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-10]C"
    Range("D13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-11]C"
    Range("D14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-12]C"
    Range("D15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-13]C"
    Range("D16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-14]C"
    Range("D17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-15]C"
    Range("D18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-16]C"
    Range("D19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-17]C"
    Range("D20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-18]C"
    Range("D21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-19]C"
    Range("D22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-20]C"
    Range("D23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-21]C"
    Range("D24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-22]C"
    Range("D25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-23]C"
    Range("D26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*R[-24]C"
    Range("E3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-1]C"
    Range("E4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-2]C"
    Range("E5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-3]C"
    Range("E6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-4]C"
    Range("E7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-5]C"
    Range("E8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-6]C"
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-7]C"
    Range("E10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-8]C"
    Range("E11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-9]C"
    Range("E12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-10]C"
    Range("E13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-11]C"
    Range("E14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-12]C"
    Range("E15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-13]C"
    Range("E16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-14]C"
    Range("E17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-15]C"
    Range("E18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-16]C"
    Range("E19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-17]C"
    Range("E20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-18]C"
    Range("E21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-19]C"
    Range("E22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-20]C"
    Range("E23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-21]C"
    Range("E24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-22]C"
    Range("E25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-23]C"
    Range("E26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*R[-24]C"
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-1]C"
    Range("F4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-2]C"
    Range("F5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-3]C"
    Range("F6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-4]C"
    Range("F7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-5]C"
    Range("F8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-6]C"
    Range("F9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-7]C"
    Range("F10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-8]C"
    Range("F11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-9]C"
    Range("F12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-10]C"
    Range("F13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-11]C"
    Range("F14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-12]C"
    Range("F15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-13]C"
    Range("F16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-14]C"
    Range("F17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-15]C"
    Range("F18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-16]C"
    Range("F19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-17]C"
    Range("F20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-18]C"
    Range("F21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-19]C"
    Range("F22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-20]C"
    Range("F23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-21]C"
    Range("F24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-22]C"
    Range("F25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-23]C"
    Range("F26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*R[-24]C"
    Range("G3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-1]C"
    Range("G4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-2]C"
    Range("G5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-3]C"
    Range("G6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-4]C"
    Range("G7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-5]C"
    Range("G8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-6]C"
    Range("G9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-7]C"
    Range("G10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-8]C"
    Range("G11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-9]C"
    Range("G12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-10]C"
    Range("G13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-11]C"
    Range("G14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-12]C"
    Range("G15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-13]C"
    Range("G16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-14]C"
    Range("G17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-15]C"
    Range("G18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-16]C"
    Range("G19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-17]C"
    Range("G20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-18]C"
    Range("G21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-19]C"
    Range("G22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-20]C"
    Range("G23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-21]C"
    Range("G24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-22]C"
    Range("G25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-23]C"
    Range("G26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*R[-24]C"
    Range("H3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-1]C"
    Range("H4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-2]C"
    Range("H5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-3]C"
    Range("H6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-4]C"
    Range("H7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-5]C"
    Range("H8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-6]C"
    Range("H9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-7]C"
    Range("H10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-8]C"
    Range("H11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-9]C"
    Range("H12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-10]C"
    Range("H13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-11]C"
    Range("H14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-12]C"
    Range("H15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-13]C"
    Range("H16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-14]C"
    Range("H17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-15]C"
    Range("H18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-16]C"
    Range("H19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-17]C"
    Range("H20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-18]C"
    Range("H21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-19]C"
    Range("H22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-20]C"
    Range("H23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-21]C"
    Range("H24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-22]C"
    Range("H25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-23]C"
    Range("H26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]*R[-24]C"
    Range("I3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-1]C"
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-2]C"
    Range("I5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-3]C"
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-4]C"
    Range("I7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-5]C"
    Range("I8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-6]C"
    Range("I9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-7]C"
    Range("I10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-8]C"
    Range("I11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-9]C"
    Range("I12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-10]C"
    Range("I13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-11]C"
    Range("I14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-12]C"
    Range("I15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-13]C"
    Range("I16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-14]C"
    Range("I17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-15]C"
    Range("I18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-16]C"
    Range("I19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-17]C"
    Range("I20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-18]C"
    Range("I21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-19]C"
    Range("I22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-20]C"
    Range("I23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-21]C"
    Range("I24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-22]C"
    Range("I25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-23]C"
    Range("I26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]*R[-24]C"
    Range("J3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-1]C"
    Range("J4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-2]C"
    Range("J5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-3]C"
    Range("J6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-4]C"
    Range("J7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-5]C"
    Range("J8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-6]C"
    Range("J9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-7]C"
    Range("J10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-8]C"
    Range("J11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-9]C"
    Range("J12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-10]C"
    Range("J13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-11]C"
    Range("J14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-12]C"
    Range("J15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-13]C"
    Range("J16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-14]C"
    Range("J17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-15]C"
    Range("J18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-16]C"
    Range("J19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-17]C"
    Range("J20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-18]C"
    Range("J21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-19]C"
    Range("J22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-20]C"
    Range("J23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-21]C"
    Range("J24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-22]C"
    Range("J25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-23]C"
    Range("J26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*R[-24]C"
    Range("K3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-1]C"
    Range("K4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-2]C"
    Range("K5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-3]C"
    Range("K6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-4]C"
    Range("K7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-5]C"
    Range("K8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-6]C"
    Range("K9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-7]C"
    Range("K10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-8]C"
    Range("K11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-9]C"
    Range("K12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-10]C"
    Range("K13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-11]C"
    Range("K14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-12]C"
    Range("K15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-13]C"
    Range("K16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-14]C"
    Range("K17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-15]C"
    Range("K18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-16]C"
    Range("K19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-17]C"
    Range("K20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-18]C"
    Range("K21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-19]C"
    Range("K22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-20]C"
    Range("K23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-21]C"
    Range("K24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-22]C"
    Range("K25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-23]C"
    Range("K26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*R[-24]C"
    Range("L3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-1]C"
    Range("L4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-2]C"
    Range("L5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-3]C"
    Range("L6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-4]C"
    Range("L7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-5]C"
    Range("L8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-6]C"
    Range("L9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-7]C"
    Range("L10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-8]C"
    Range("L11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-9]C"
    Range("L12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-10]C"
    Range("L13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-11]C"
    Range("L14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-12]C"
    Range("L15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-13]C"
    Range("L16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-14]C"
    Range("L17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-15]C"
    Range("L18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-16]C"
    Range("L19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-17]C"
    Range("L20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-18]C"
    Range("L21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-19]C"
    Range("L22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-20]C"
    Range("L23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-21]C"
    Range("L24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-22]C"
    Range("L25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-23]C"
    Range("L26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*R[-24]C"
    Range("M3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-1]C"
    Range("M4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-2]C"
    Range("M5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-3]C"
    Range("M6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-4]C"
    Range("M7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-5]C"
    Range("M8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-6]C"
    Range("M9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-7]C"
    Range("M10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-8]C"
    Range("M11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-9]C"
    Range("M12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-10]C"
    Range("M13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-11]C"
    Range("M14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-12]C"
    Range("M15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-13]C"
    Range("M16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-14]C"
    Range("M17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-15]C"
    Range("M18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-16]C"
    Range("M19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-17]C"
    Range("M20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-18]C"
    Range("M21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-19]C"
    Range("M22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-20]C"
    Range("M23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-21]C"
    Range("M24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-22]C"
    Range("M25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-23]C"
    Range("M26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]*R[-24]C"
    Range("N3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-1]C"
    Range("N4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-2]C"
    Range("N5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-3]C"
    Range("N6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-4]C"
    Range("N7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-5]C"
    Range("N8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-6]C"
    Range("N9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-7]C"
    Range("N10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-8]C"
    Range("N11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-9]C"
    Range("N12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-10]C"
    Range("N13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-11]C"
    Range("N14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-12]C"
    Range("N15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-13]C"
    Range("N16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-14]C"
    Range("N17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-15]C"
    Range("N18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-16]C"
    Range("N19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-17]C"
    Range("N20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-18]C"
    Range("N21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-19]C"
    Range("N22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-20]C"
    Range("N23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-21]C"
    Range("N24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-22]C"
    Range("N25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-23]C"
    Range("N26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*R[-24]C"
    Range("O3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-12]+RC[-11]+RC[-10]+RC[-9]+RC[-8]+RC[-7]+RC[-6]+RC[-5]+RC[-4]+RC[-3]+RC[-2]+RC[-1]"
    Range("O3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O3:O26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("O3:O26").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edited after OP's comment

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Worksheets.count
        With Worksheets(i).Range("C3:O26")
            .Resize(, Columns.count - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC2*R2C"
            .Columns(.Columns.count).Resize(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-12]:RC[-1])"
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```